# Why is my KitchenAid dual ring burner not lighting?

Tags: gas, stove, gas-burner

I have a KitchenAid 36 inch countertop stove, model KFGU766VSS02. The center burner high power won't light. Center low power does light.

This is one of the KitchenAid "dual ring" burners. It has a very low BTU center for simmering and a very high BTU burner on outside for wok/griddle/etc.

I think the lighting principle of it is that the electric spark will light the small burner and the small burner will light the big burner if gas is present (may be mistaken).

The spark works on all burners.

What happens when I attempt to light the large center burner is that the stove will click - as if trying to light - then it will all go off - apparently as a safety mechanism from not lighting.

I don't smell any additional gas coming from the larger burner tube.

I did pull off the top to check for obstructions. All burners clean with good inlets. I tried blowing air from the high BTU side to the low BTU side and air does flow - so I don't think it's the valve necessarily.

I wonder if something electronically thinks the burner isn't working? Or am I wrong and there should be a separate spark just for that larger burner? The burners are not readily available anymore and would be a very expensive lesson if that's not the issue.

Comment: What happens if you try to light the big burner while having a burning lighter/match next to it? Does it light then and does it keep burning?

Comment: I didn't try that. What I did try while plugged in was to light the center (joy) then turn on the outer ring (keeps clicking / no joy). I found a method to light manually while not plugged in so I will try that, too, to check for flow/valves/etc. Thanks!

Comment: Have you deep cleaned all the little jets in the lift-out rings? My KitchenAid dual burner was finicky until I did that.

Comment: Yep - deep cleaned everything. The actual jets were not blocked. Both the low power and high power side jets were clear when looking at a light through them.